# How to use properly nested mongoose model and schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my schema. I am new to mongoose but trying the policy why to send extra info when not required. I have tried to do a subDocument for comments and likes.

```
var post = new Schema({
    postid: {type: Number, required: true, unique: true},
    title: {type: String, required: [true, 'Title cannot be blank']},
    startdate: {type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now},
    enddate: {type: Date, required: true, default: new Date(+new Date() + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)},
    comments: [
        {
            id: {type: Number, required: true},
            message: {type: String, required: true},
            userid: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
            updated_at: {type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now, select: false},
            likes: [
                {
                    userid: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
                    updated_at: {type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now},
                }
            ],
        }
    ],
}, {
    timestamps: {
        createdAt: 'created_at',
        updatedAt: 'updated_at'
    }
});

post.index({postid: 1});
```

I am doing some dirty tricks to get the data in rest api by using `lean()`.

```
// post [GET]
[
   { postid: 1, title: "dfdsfadsf", startdate: "dafdsfadsf", enddate: "dsafdsfads", commentscount: 6},
   { postid: 2, title: "ffdsfadsf", startdate: "dafdsfadsf", enddate: "dsafdsfads", commentscount: 5},
]
```

```
// post/:id [GET]
{
    postid: 1,
    title: "dfdsfadsf",
    startdate: "dafdsfadsf",
    enddate: "dsafdsfads",
    comments: [{
        {id: 1, message: "ddsfsfadsfa", likescount: 6},
        {id: 2, message: "dsfafdrsdsfa", likescount: 3},
        {id: 3, message: "dsfaefdsdsfa", likescount: 4},
        {id: 4, message: "dfsfdsfadsfa", likescount: 5},
        {id: 5, message: "fdsfdsfadsfa", likescount: 7},
        {id: 6, message: "dsfadwsfadsf", likescount: 0}
    }]
}
```

```
// post/:id/comments/:commentid/likes [GET]
{
    id: "1",
    message: "fadsfads",
    likes: [
        { userid: 1, updated_at: "some date" },
        { userid: 2, updated_at: "some date" },
        { userid: 3, updated_at: "some date" },
        { userid: 4, updated_at: "some date" },
        { userid: 5, updated_at: "some date" },
        { userid: 6, updated_at: "some date" }
    ]
}
```

Using mysql it was pretty easy to use an ORM and do all these with one single query. Now in mongoose I am doing this in a bad way, like

for the first route, I am doing

```
Posts.find({}).select({
    postid: true,
    title: true,
    startdate: true,
    enddate: true,
    comments: true
}).lean().exec(function(err, doc){
    if (doc) {
       if(doc.comments.length > 0) {
          doc.commentcount = doc.comments.length;
          delete doc.comments;
       }
    } 
});
```

Same way I am doing for other two routes. I feel there might be a proper way to do all these using mongoose model. I have tried using `aggregate` & `populate`. But not my piece of cake.

If anyone can guide how to use the ORM and fetch data properly for one, I'll be glad and can do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can only add `likescount: {type: Number}` in `comments` field and increment this field when `.push` new object to `likes` field.

Comment: Won't it be extra burden for maintaining that part like on new creation increment, on deletion decrement.